# Defining a new timestamp in Logstash

Tags: logging, timestamp, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I'm trying to define a new timestamp in Logstash, in order to use the timestamp of the logs in my Kibana reportings instead of the Filebeat timestamp.

I had the following, which was working but didn't let me use the log timestamp as a time axis in Kibana:

```
grok {
    match => { "message" => "(?<timestamp>%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}) %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} (?<class>[A-Za-z0-9$_.]+) %{NOTSPACE:method}\(%{JAVAFILE:class}:%{NONNEGINT:line}\) %{GREEDYDATA:message}$"
}
```

So I modified it like this, but it's not working:

```
grok {
    match => { "message" => "(?<timestamp>%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:tstamp}) %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} (?<class>[A-Za-z0-9$_.]+) %{NOTSPACE:method}\(%{JAVAFILE:class}:%{NONNEGINT:line}\) %{GREEDYDATA:message}$"
}

date {
    match => ["tstamp", "TIMESTAMP_ISO8601"]
}
```

I tried to add what I think is a naming of the value inside of the Grok pattern (the ":tstamp" part), which I found [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/replace-timestamp-with-actual-timestamp-from-log-file/72017/3), and the define that as a date. But when I use that, I don't see any data in Kibana anymore.

I erased everything in Kibana in order to have a fresh start, and I deleted the "registry" file in Filebeat in order to make it stream the log file again.

What am I missing?

**Edit:** I was able to restore the data flow by changing my filters like that:

```
grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:tstamp} %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} (?<class>[A-Za-z0-9$_.]+) %{NOTSPACE:method}\(%{JAVAFILE:class}:%{NONNEGINT:line}\) %{GREEDYDATA:message}$" }
}

date {
    match => ["tstamp", "ISO8601"]
}
```

But I still only see the `@timestamp` as Time Filter. tstamp is still considered as a string. I don't get it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were actually 2 distinct problems in what I made.

As I indicated my edit of the question, the date filter was wrong. I had to use

```
match => ["tstamp", "ISO8601"]
```

with `"ISO8601"` instead of `"TIMESTAMP_ISO8601"`.

At that point, things were actually working, even if it wasn't obvious, because by default, Logstash overwrites the value of `@timestamp` with the result of the date filter. To avoid that, I had to use the `target` option:

```
target => "logdate"
```

I now have a `logdate` field in Kibana, of type `date` and I can select it as time filter when creating a pattern.

So my final filters in Logstash look like that:

```
grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:tstamp} %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} (?<class>[A-Za-z0-9$_.]+) %{NOTSPACE:method}\(%{JAVAFILE:class}:%{NONNEGINT:line}\) %{GREEDYDATA:message}$" }
}

date {
    match => ["tstamp", "ISO8601"]
    target => "logdate"
}
```